# Cannot find selector for my ChatGPT extension

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, firefox-addon

I made a Firefox Add-on that adds an "Upload File" button to chat.openai.com. I had it finished, then the May 24 Version released, breaking it entirely. I'm pretty sure it is the selector, the place the button is inserted. In the previous version, this code worked:

```
// Function to inject the button
function injectButton() {
  // Find the target element
  const targetElement = document.querySelector("div.relative.flex.h-full.max-w-full.flex-1.overflow-hidden > div > main > div.absolute.bottom-0 > form > div > div:nth-child(1)");
```

My full js document is located here: https://github.com/TETRA326/ChatGPT-File-Upload/blob/main/content.js

I'm unsure how to find the new area for the selector and would appreciate any help!

Links:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chatgpt-file-upload/

https://github.com/TETRA326/ChatGPT-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution proposed by ChatGPT, which is to change to `document.getElementsByClassName()`. In Vivaldi/Chrome, with the updated element naming, the command looks like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("flex flex-col w-full py-[10px] flex-grow md:py-4 md:pl-4 relative border border-black/10 bg-white dark:border-gray-900/50 dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-xl shadow-xs dark:shadow-xs")[0]
```